# iOS app crashing on launch - built via Expo

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, npm, expo

I am using Expo to build my iOS app. I am unsure of how I can access my code on XCode as this is my first time building an iOS app.

I can see that the error is due to the RCT Native Module, but have no clue of how to proceed. Should I shift to pure React Native so that I can actually view the origin of the error on XCode to avoid this in the future?

I am just the backtrace here for quick reference. Pls check my error log attached with this question. Thank you very much!

Last Exception Backtrace:

0   CoreFoundation                  0x188251e88 __exceptionPreprocess + 164 (NSException.m:202)

1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1815878d8 objc_exception_throw + 60 (objc-exception.mm:356)

2   Shram                           0x10282cd18 RCTFatal + 568 (RCTAssert.m:147)

3   Shram                           0x10289fcac -[RCTExceptionsManager reportFatal:stack:exceptionId:extraDataAsJSON:] + 476 (RCTExceptionsManager.mm:77)

4   Shram                           0x1028a04f0 -[RCTExceptionsManager reportException:] + 1292 (RCTExceptionsManager.mm:147)

5   CoreFoundation                  0x1882bc704 **invoking**_ + 148

6   CoreFoundation                  0x188268b6c -[NSInvocation invoke] + 428 (NSForwarding.m:3377)
7   CoreFoundation                  0x188268584 -[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] + 64 (NSForwarding.m:3474)

8   Shram                           0x10285abbc -[RCTModuleMethod invokeWithBridge:module:arguments:] + 388 (RCTModuleMethod.mm:584)

9   Shram                           0x10285cd34 facebook::react::invokeInner(RCTBridge*, RCTModuleData*, unsigned int, folly::dynamic const&, int, (anonymous namespace)::SchedulingContext) + 452 (RCTNativeModule.mm:183)

10  Shram                           0x10285c9bc facebook::react::RCTNativeModule::invoke(unsigned int, folly::dynamic&&, int)::$_0::operator()() const + 68 (RCTNativeModule.mm:104)

11  Shram                           0x10285c9bc invocation function for block in facebook::react::RCTNativeModule::invoke(unsigned int, folly::dynamic&&, int) + 112 (RCTNativeModule.mm:95)

12  libdispatch.dylib               0x18f8204b4 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32 (init.c:1518)

13  libdispatch.dylib               0x18f821fdc _dispatch_client_callout + 20 (object.m:560)

14  libdispatch.dylib               0x18f829694 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 672 (inline_internal.h:2632)

15  libdispatch.dylib               0x18f82a1e0 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 384 (queue.c:3940)

16  libdispatch.dylib               0x18f834e10 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 652 (queue.c:6846)

17  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1d52a7df8 _pthread_wqthread + 288 (pthread.c:2618)

18  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1d52a7b98 start_wqthread + 8

I have tried deleting node packages and package-lock.json and install again via npm install.
I also tried to find where I am using this module - RCT Native Module but couldn't figure out.

I also wish to know how I can access code on XCode since Expo directly makes the build. Should I shift to pure React Native to avoid this in the future?